# Npm postinstall only on development

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, npm

I have npm module with following `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "bower install",
    "build": "gulp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.6.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.2"
  }
}
```

When I deploy my app to production, I don't want install `devDependecies`, so, I run `npm install --production`. But in this case, `prepublish` script is called, but it doesn't need to, because I use CDN links in production.

How to call `postinstall` script only after `npm install` but not after `npm install --production`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Newer npm (& Yarn) versions include support for the `prepare` script that is run after each `install` run but only in development mode. Also, the `prepublish` is deprecated. This should be enough:

```
{
  scripts: {
    "prepare": "bower install"
  }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: It appears later versions of npm (e.g. v6 and v7) run `prepare` on both dev and production installs now.

Comment: Yes, this answer is wrong. The npm script prepare does run in both prod and dev modes.

Comment: npm totally botched this :face_palm

Comment: With yarn this works perfectly!

Comment: I forked and created https://www.npmjs.com/package/@znemz/skip-npm-task to specifically deal with this problem.

Answer (score 29):

I think you cannot choose what scripts are run based on the `--production` argument.  What you can do, however, is supply a script which tests the `NODE_ENV` variable and only runs `bower install` if it's not "production".

If you are always in a unix-y environment, you can do it like this:

```
{ 
  scripts: {
    "prepublish": "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" = production ] && exit 0; bower install"
  }
}
```

Comment: nice answer! what if i want to also include "beta" enviroment? how can i add the "production OR beta" condition?

Comment: Then it starts to get complicated -- but you can do

`"[ \"$NODE_ENV\" = production ] || [ \"$NODE_ENV\" = beta ] || bower install"`

Comment: My NPM fails if I have this script and run it in production mode, as it returns a non-zero exit code. It works with: `[ \"$npm_config_production\" ] && exit 0; bower install` or  `[ \"$NODE_ENV\" == production ] && exit 0; bower install`

Comment: I think it worth updating this answer based on last comment @SamMikes

Comment: I think it would be even better if this answer reommended [cross-env](https://npmjs.com/package/cross-env) instead of using bash-only constructs. It's really actually easier and your build will be cross-platform.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you. I use it to ensure that `husky` only runs in development environments when `npm install` is executed, i.e. `"prepare": "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" = production ] && exit 0; cd ../../ && husky install"`

Answer (score 17):

This only works if you're on a unix-like environment:

NPM sets an environment variable to "true" when install is run with --production. To only run the postinstall script if npm install was not run with --production, use the following code.

```
"postinstall": "if [ -z \"$npm_config_production\" ]; then node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js first-run; fi",
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the reverse for building assets only on heroku deploys: `"postinstall": "if [ -n \"$npm_config_production\" ]; then npm run build-for-production; fi"`

Answer (score 13):

Solution that is less dependent on unix nature of your shell:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node -e \"process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production' && process.exit(1)\" || echo do dev stuff"
  },
```

Comment: This fails when I add this module to another module as a dependency and try to `npm install` the encompassing one. Modifying the return value of the command chain fixes this for me: `"(node -e \"process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.exit()\" && grunt devTask) || node -v"`

Comment: FYI: This still works in 2022 and it was the only one-liner solution for me

Comment: If you have a lot of concatenated scripts, it's a good idea to wrap them in brackets, i.e. `(node -e "process.env.GITHUB_ACTION && console.log('skip postinstall')") || (npm run clean && npm run build)`

Answer (score 12):

I work with windows, osx and linux so I use a NON environment specific solution to solve this problem:

In the *postinstall* handler i execute a js script that checks process.env.NODE_ENV variable and does the work.

in my specific case I have to execute a gulp task only in development env:

**part of package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "node postinstall"
}
```

**all postinstall.js script**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const gulp = require('./gulpfile');
  gulp.start('taskname');
}
```

**last row of gulpfile.js**

```
module.exports = gulp;
```

it's important to export gulp from the gulpfile.js because all tasks are in that specific gulp instance.

Answer (score 6):

I have a more general problem - where I want to skip running the `postinstall` script on local (direct) installs - like when I'm developing the package and run `yarn add --dev my-new-dependency`.

This is what I came up with. It works with both npm and yarn.

**postinstall.js**:

```
const env = process.env;
if (
    // if INIT_CWD (yarn/npm install invocation path) and PWD
    // are the same, then local (dev) install/add is taking place
    env.INIT_CWD === env.PWD ||
    // local (dev) yarn install may have been run
    // from a project subfolder
    env.INIT_CWD.indexOf(env.PWD) === 0
) {
    console.info('Skipping `postinstall` script on local installs');
}
else {
    // do post-installation things
    // ...
}
```

**package.json**:

```
"script": {
    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js",
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Created a npm package to do just that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/skip-local-postinstall

Comment: Matthias your package looks great but it would be great to have flags cause I actually need this inverted.

Answer (score 5):

Landed here because I had the same issue. Ended up with a solution that tests for the existence of a package under node_modules that I know should only be available in development.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bash -c '[ -d ./node_modules/@types ] && lerna run prepare || echo No postinstall without type info'" 
  }
}
```

This works fine for me conceptually, as the prepare scripts here called by lerna are mainly to ts-to-js compilations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [if-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/if-env) module. It's less verbose.

***PS***: I didn't test it on windows yet.

Install with:

```
npm i if-env
```

than in `package.json` scripts:

```
"postinstall-production": "echo \"production, skipping...\"",
"postinstall-dev": "echo \"doing dev exclusive stuff\"",
"postinstall": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run postinstall-production || npm run postinstall-dev"
```

Comment: Does this mean that `if-env` has to be in `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`?