# Angular 2 npm install typings error

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, typescript-typings

Every time I try to run npm install on an angular 2 project I am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! pantree@0.0.1 preinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pantree@0.0.1 preinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pantree package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pantree
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pantree
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ian/Documents/mean/npm-debug.log
```

I have followed a number of steps, including installing typings globally prior to running npm install, uninstalling all global npm packages and ensuring that I have the most up to date node and npm versions.

Could anyone explain the reason for this happening and what the solution might be? This happens both when creating the file manually through the quickstart project on the angular site and when built through yeoman. This makes me doubt that it is an error with the package itself as is being suggested in the error message.

If anyone is able to shine some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: I'm not no. Does this suggest that I may be?

Comment: Why not use angular CLI

Comment: @helenkitt No, just wanted to rule that out. A lot of these errors occur because people don't know that typings have their own proxy settings (not using the npm ones). -- can you show us your config files, package.json typings.json?

Comment: I am a little too late but maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662790/npm-post-install-typings-not-working-correctly