# Npm postinstall only on development on Windows

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, bower-install

Basically I need this:

[Npm postinstall only on development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076968/npm-postinstall-only-on-development)

But here on company we have several machines running Windows on development. What to do?

Comment: I have updated original question with answer that could work on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40551128/788374

Comment: this is a non environment specific solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41449705/5279334

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use the format `IF NOT %NODE_ENV% == production <script here>`. 
I have this in package.json to run bower & typings when doing a dev (non-production) install:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "IF NOT %NODE_ENV% == production (bower install & typings install)"
}
```

See for example [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/) for documentation of available commands etc.