# What kind of NPM script to use when I want it to be executed during every npm install w/o arguments?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I want to build a tool that is run on every npm install call, just like the `npm audit`.

For now, I have used the `postinstall` script, simply because it works. 
This is what the output looks like of a `npm install` command:

```
    users-MacBook-Pro:hello_world user$ npm install
    >hello_world@1.0.0 postinstall /Users/user/my-nice-tool/hello_world
    >node hello_world.js
    Hello World!
    up to date in 0.494s
    found 0 vulnerabilities
```

My tool shows "Hello World!" just above the built-in vulnerability check (`npm audit`), which is perfectly fine and wanted.

At the moment, my `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{ bla bla,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node hello_world.js"
  },
   bla bla
}
```

But then I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23076968/11957512) and its answers, which stated that there are types of scripts that are not always run, depending on the mode they are run in/the arguments passed to `npm install`...

So my question is: does anyone know what kind of script I should use, just to make sure that my tool works as I want it to every time?